# Full text search with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am getting wrong result after running this query:

```
select 
    a.userid as userid,
    b.CompanyProfile as cp,  
    MATCH ( b.fldsearch ) AGAINST ( '+(computers computer) +(hardawre hardawres)' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) as rank
from users a , companymaster b
where a.userid=b.userid and MATCH ( b.fldsearch ) 
AGAINST ('+(computers computer) +(hardawre hardawres)' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

I need only those result which contain any combination of mentioned keywords means  "computer", "computers" with "hardawre", "hardawres"

And the result which I am getting from above query containing either only computer OR computers but NOT with hardawre OR hardawres

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, your problem has most likely nothing to do with it. You are probably experiencing this problem during tests and with innodb-tables.

Fulltext indexes for innodb have an a little unintuitive behaviour. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

> **InnoDB Full-Text Index Transaction Handling**
>
> InnoDB FULLTEXT indexes have special transaction handling characteristics due its caching and batch processing behavior. Specifically, updates and insertions on a FULLTEXT index are processed at transaction commit time, which means that a FULLTEXT search can only see committed data.

So if you are working e.g. with the workbench, you just have to `commit;` your data (or use a command with an autocommit) after you added new (test-)words to add these to your fulltext index so your query can see them.